# convert NSTextField to Label

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I am using following functions for converting textfield to label and vice versa

```
-(void)convertLabelToTextField : (NSTextField *)Inlabel
{
    [Inlabel setBezeled:YES];
    [Inlabel setDrawsBackground:YES];
    [Inlabel setEditable:YES];
    [Inlabel setSelectable:YES];
}

-(void)convertTextFieldToLable : (NSTextField *)textField
{

    [textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [textField setEditable:NO];
    [textField setSelectable:NO];
    [textField setBezeled:NO];

}
```

But my UI is not consistent.

- Initial Label

[image]

- Label to textfield

[image]

- Textfield to Label  (after selecting text)

[image]

- Label to textfield

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Culprit was default hight of label.

label Default height

[image]

NSTextField Default height

[image: hight of textfield]

below is code for Label with height 22

```
NSTextField *textField;

textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 22)];
[textField setStringValue:@"My Label"];
[textField setBezeled:NO];
[textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
[textField setEditable:NO];
[textField setSelectable:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Resizing mask

```
[textField setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin | NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin | NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewMaxYMargin];
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507665/1704346)